# How do I execute a callback when the Enter key is pressed after entering text into a Text widget?

Tags: python, text, callback, tkinter

I've really tried to find this out but have only discovered disconnected snippets such as `tag_bind`. I cannot work out how to use this (if indeed this is the right way forward).

I've got a Text widget into which the user can enter some text (such as a command or question) and I'd like to execute a function that reads that text then responds to it. Obviously I could provide a nearby Button widget which when clicked, reads the text in the Text widget. But I don't want people to have to move their hand from the keyboard to the mouse. I'd just like the callback to be triggered if they hit the Enter key. How do I do it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Tkinter as tk

def on_enter(event):
    widget = event.widget
    print(widget.get())

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry()
entry.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
entry.focus()
entry.bind('<Return>', on_enter)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Unutbu. Please, what does the 'entry.focus_set()' do and where does that come from?

Comment: `focus_set` is the same as `focus`. It sets the `Entry` widget as the active widget. If you didn't do this, then when the program starts you would have to click on the `Entry` before you start to type. (Or you'd have to press `TAB` to select the `Entry`.) By calling `entry.focus()`, you can just start typing.

Comment: Brilliant, and eloquently explained, Sir.